# Getting NameError: `format' is not allowed as an instance variable name when testing instance variable with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following test:

```
let(:client) { Descat::Client.new }

describe 'poblacio' do
  it 'should set format correctly' do
    client.poblacio('v1','json','dades')
    expect (client.instance_variable_get(:format)).to eq('json')
  end
end
```

And I have the following code that is being tested:

```
module Descat
  class Client
    BASE_URL = 'http://api.idescat.cat/'

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      attributes.each do |attr, value|
        self.send("#{attr}=", value)
      end
    end

    def poblacio(version, format, operation, *args)
      @format = format
    end
  end
end
```

WHen running the tests I keep getting '

```
Failure/Error: expect (client.instance_variable_get(:format)).to eq('json')
     NameError:
```

But, changing the name doesnt help.

'

Comment: Why are you checking for the presence of an instance variable rather than checking that the accessor method returns the right thing.

Comment: I don't have an accessor for that instance variable. It belongs to the object, but it is not needed that it can be readed from it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To use [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) you have to provide the name starting with `"@"`. In your case:

```
client.instance_variable_get('@format')
```